# Tool/Utility for copying one file inside another

Tags: windows, command-line, file-management

I'm looking for Tool/Utility with which I could copy one file inside another, but with option to specify target location in second file. And it must overwrite overlapping content not insert.

for example I've file A.dat with content "ABCDE" and second file B.dat with content "1234567890"

so I specify to copy A.dat inside B.dat at 4th byte and result file would be "123ABCDE90"

it must be with command-line interface and for Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [dd for windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd)

```
dd if=A.dat of=B.dat seek=4 bs=1 count=5
```

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [dd for Windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd). "dd" is a unix utility to do exactly what you're asking for, and there are several Windows ports available.